# How-to use FindItemWithText?

Tags: vb.net, listview, virtualmode

Below is the code I am working with. My accounts are stored in a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) so that I can easily associate a value with them. My listview is working great after I converted it to virtualmode but I lost the functionality to search simply by typing in the listview which is what I would like to get back. Without it this makes the whole feature practically useless unless I can search by name. I have searched and implemented multiple examples and I cannot get anything to work. What am I doing wrong? How should it look?

This populates my listview.

```
Private Sub lstAccounts_RetrieveVirtualItem(sender As Object, e As RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs) Handles lstAccounts.RetrieveVirtualItem
    lstAccounts.VirtualListSize = MainForm.accounts.Count 'Update after a dictionary edit.

    Dim i As New ListViewItem(MainForm.accounts.Keys(e.ItemIndex))
    If MainForm.accounts.ContainsKey(MainForm.accounts.Keys(e.ItemIndex).ToString) Then
        i.SubItems.Add(MainForm.accounts.Item(i.Text))
    End If
    e.Item = i
End Sub
```

This is from MSDN. Supposedly required for searching, only example I could find..

```
Private Sub lstAccounts_SearchForVirtualItem(sender As Object, e As SearchForVirtualItemEventArgs) Handles lstAccounts.SearchForVirtualItem
    Dim x As Double = 0
    If [Double].TryParse(e.Text, x) Then 'check if this is a valid search
        x = Math.Sqrt(x)
        x = Math.Round(x)
        e.Index = Fix(x)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is also from the MSDN. No matter what I search for it constantly returns null.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim item1 As ListViewItem = lstAccounts.FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text)
    If (item1 IsNot Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Calling FindItemWithText passing" & TextBox1.Text & ": " _
            & item1.ToString())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Calling FindItemWithText passing" & TextBox1.Text & ": null")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was really hoping someone might be able to help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler for the `SearchForVirtualItem` event, you must search your dictionary and then tell the `ListView` the index of the row that matched what was typed.

Guessing that you want to search the text, you want something like this:

```
foreach (var x in MainForm.accounts) {
    if (x.Value == e.Text) {
        e.Index = x.Key;
        return;
    }
}
```

BTW, it's better to update the size of the virtual list somewhere else. The handler for the RetrieveVirtualItem event is not the right place to change the size of the list.