# Search for ListViewItem in VirtualMode

Tags: c#, listview, virtualmode

I'm having some trouble doing a search in a ListView when using VirtualMode. The ListView populates just find using RetrieveVirtualItem event.

I have a text box and "Search" button on my form.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listViewFields.FindItemWithText(txtSearch.Text);
}
```

I have handled the SearchForVirtualItem event that looks for the text in my collection and sets the index to the Index property of the event args.

```
private void listViewFields_SearchForVirtualItem(object sender, SearchForVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
        e.Index = collection.IndexOf(e.Text);
}
```

The value of e.Index does get set to the expected value but then nothing happens in my ListView.

Comment: have you considered looking at the MSDN four [ListView.SearchForVirtualItem Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.searchforvirtualitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's what I'm using. If you notice my second code block I'm handling that event. The FindItemWithText method triggers that event and the value of e.Text in the event args is the value I passed to FindItemWithText. Nothing happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129619/how-to-use-finditemwithtext

Comment: The answer given in that link is exactly what I'm doing. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of e.Index does get set to the expected value but then nothing happens in my ListView.

The [`FindItemWithText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385(v=vs.110).aspx) method does exactly what it says - finds and **returns** the first ListViewItem that begins with the specified text value.

In order something to happen in your list view, you have to do something with the returned item. For instance:

```
var item = listViewFields.FindItemWithText(txtSearch.Text);
if (item != null)
{
    listViewFields.FocusedItem = item;
    item.Selected = true;
    item.EnsureVisible();
}
```

Comment: Does it return something?

Comment: Yes, it does. It returns the item I was expecting. The problem is that the list view doesn't go to that item.

Comment: It depends what do you mean by "go to that item". The above is just example, it really focuses the item, but you don't see it until the focus goes to the list view. Again, the action depends on what do you want to happen.

Comment: I want the item that matches the search condition to become visible within the ListView. So let's say I've at the top of the list and the first 10 list items are showing. I search for an item that is the 200th item in the list. I want the ListView to jump to the 200th item.

Comment: Well, this was noit mentioned in the question. Does the update work for you?

Answer (score 0):

it's easy you need another List to save the found index's to the stuff you searched for from your original List. Mine 2 List is **result** und my original list is **m_sTable1_DataList**.

```
private List<int> result = null;
```

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == '\r')
        {
            string sSearchValue = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd();                      

            if (sSearchValue.Length > 0)
            {     

                listViewDB1.FindItemWithText(sSearchValue);
                //Select the item found and scroll it into view.
            }
        }
    }
```

```
        private void listViewDB1_SearchForVirtualItem(object sender, SearchForVirtualItemEventArgs e)
        {
            result = Enumerable.Range(0, m_sTable1_DataList.Count)
         .Where(i => m_sTable1_DataList[i].Contains(textBox1.Text.ToString().TrimEnd()))
         .ToList();
            if (result.Count > 0)
                listViewDB1.VirtualListSize = result.Count;
            else
            {
                result = null;      
                this.listViewDB1.VirtualListSize = 0;
            }
        }
```

```
    private void listViewDB1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (result != null)
            e.Item = new ListViewItem(m_sTable1_DataList[result[e.ItemIndex]]);
        else
            e.Item = new ListViewItem(m_sTable1_DataList[e.ItemIndex]);
    }
```

```
i have a reset button to come back to the orginal list and VirtualListSize.
```

```
private void Resetbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        listViewDB2.Items.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Refresh();  
        result = null;
        this.listViewDB1.VirtualListSize = nCountRow;
    }
```